# Create 2 way function

Tags: php, math

I'm struggling to create a similar function but currently I have the following function:

```
//$amount (int) (anything from 10000 - 1000000)
//$platform (string) (XBOX or PS)

private function getPrice($platform, $amount) {
    $price = DB::table('platform_prices')->where('platform', $platform)->first();
    return $amount / 10000 * $price->price_per_10k;
}
```

This basically gets the price of a currency for a specified platform (which is stored in the DB based on per 10,000 currency).

As an example:

```
return $this->getPrice('XBOX', '50000'); //3.50
```

How can I create the same function but accepting the **3.50** as a value for `$amount` & have it return **50000**.

Comment: your question is not  clear .. why you can't build a separated  function ??

Comment: Create new function, write logic in it, use.

Comment: @u_mulder I'm struggling to think of the logic

Comment: Without understanding what is `$amount` there's nothing to say.

Comment: This shows no research effort. Really, you should have a go at it, show your attempt and tell us what the problem is with your attempt. This really is not hard to do. Just swap the variables, where clause, ...etc

Comment: Divide `3.5` by `price_per_10k` and multiply by 10k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing down on a sheet of paper

```
if `$price = $amount / 10000 * price_per_10k` 
then `$amount = $price * 10000 / price_per_10k`
```

As a function:

```
private function getWhatever($platform, $price) {
    $priceData = DB::table('platform_prices')->where('platform', $platform)->first();
    return $price * 10000 / $priceData->price_per_10k;
}
```